# Lie derivative of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $M$ be a Kähler manifold, with Kähler metric $g$. Let $X$ be a holomorphic Killing vector field of $g$, i.e. $\mathcal{L}_{X} g = 0$, where $\mathcal{L}_{X}$ is the Lie derivative along $X$. Let $R$ be the Riemannian curvature tensor of $g$. Is $\mathcal{L}_{X} R = 0$?

Comment: certainly, $\mathcal{L}_X(Ric)=0$ and $\mathcal{L}_X(R)=0$, where $Ric$ is the Ricci form and $R$ is the scalar curvature, but I couldn't see there is any reason for $\mathcal{L}_X R=0$. Is there some motivation to consider $\mathcal{L}_X(R)=0$?

Answer (score 3):

True. $X$ is Killing, $\mathcal{L}_{X} g = 0$, iff its flow, say $\phi_t$, is by isometries, ie $\phi_t^*g=g$ for all $t$. The Riemann curvature tensor is naturally associated with the metric, hence $\phi_t^*R=R$ for all $t$. Taking derivative wrt $t$ of both sides of the last equation gives $\mathcal{L}_{X} R = 0$. Note that the Kahler structure does not play any role.

Comment: For a homogeneous space, can we say $\mathcal{L}_VR$ for any $V$? If not, can we make some similar statement? Thanks!